# How to stop SQL injection in Django column of a model

Tags: python, sql, django, security, sql-injection

So I know that Django naturally handles sql injections for columns in tables but my team want to do more. We have a help_message table in Django and there is a column in that table called Message which is a string. We do not want to save that message directly as a string in that column because of possible sql injection and malicious use. What can we do to stop sql injection and save that message in the table in Django?

Comment: [Django’s querysets are protected from SQL injection](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/security/#sql-injection-protection)

Answer (score -1):

send your data to a function like this one:

```
if($value!=''){
$value=strip_tags($value);
$first=strlen($value);
$value=addslashes($value);
$value=htmlspecialchars($value,ENT_QUOTES);
$secend=strlen($value);
if($first!=$secend)
$value="";
}
return $value;
}
```

Comment: Would I able to use the above cleaning function in my Views.py function before using the data?

Comment: The above code seems to be in PHP and I tried to transpile it into Python and was not able to. Can Someone help give me the Python equivalent?

Comment: @TritonKid this function is a horrible cargo cult code ans should never be used in php least transpiled elsewhere